# Can I refactor my linq select?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following:

```
        var data1 = contentRepository.GetPk(pk);
        var data2 = from d in data1
                    select new Content.RowKeyTitle {
                        RowKey = d.RowKey,
                        Title = d.Title,
                        Notes = d.Notes
                    };
        return (data2);
```

Is there a way I could combine data1 and data2 into one expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use lambda expressions instead of comprehension syntax

```
return contentRepository.GetPk(pk).Select(d => new Content.RowKeyTitle {
                    RowKey = d.RowKey,
                    Title = d.Title,
                    Notes = d.Notes
                });
```

Answer (score 5):

Just use the `GetPk` method directly? Then you don't need `data1` at all.

```
var data = from d in contentRepository.GetPk(pk)
           select new Content.RowKeyTitle
           {
               RowKey = d.RowKey,
               Title = d.Title,
               Notes = d.Notes
           };
return data;
```